# Installing Ubuntu from flash drive but error says it can't find the CD-ROM

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, flash, cd

First, I've never tried installing any flavor of Linux before, so bear with me. I created a bootable flash drive using Universal USB Installer. I ran the Ubuntu installer, but it quickly errors out with several error messages:

```
Install: invalid user 'ubuntu'
Install: invalid user 'ubuntu'
Using CD-ROM mount point /cdrom/
...
E: Line 1 too long in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.
E: No CD-ROM could be auto-detected or found using the default mount point.
You may try the --cdrom option to set the CD-ROM mount point.
See 'man apt-cdrom' for more information about the CD-ROM auto-detection and mount point.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/per15/Debconf/Config.pm line 22.
Umount: cant umount /cdrom: Device or resource busy
Umount: cant umount /cdrom: Device or resource busy
Umount: cant umount /cdrom: Device or resource busy
...
Chown: invalid user: 'root:ssl-cert'
pwchk: cannot open /etc/passwd
chown: invalid user: 'root:root'
chmod: cannot access '/etc/passwd': Input/output error
chown: invalid user: 'root:shadow'
usermod: user 'root' does not exist
install: 'invalid user 'ubuntu'
install: 'invalid user 'ubuntu'
```

After that it just stalls indefinitely.
There seem to be a number of things going on here, and I have no idea. It mentions the CD-ROM several times, but I am using a flash drive, not a CD or DVD. I verified that the CD drive was connected correctly. I even tried disconnecting it just to take it out of the equation, but it made no difference. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu in vmware?

Comment: @KasiyA I'm not sure what that is, so imma say no :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was some error in the .iso file. I re-downloaded, checked the md5 sum, and the install went smoothly.